# Custom registration form with Yesod.Auth.Email

Tags: haskell, yesod

I have a question regarding why Yesod.Auth was done the way it was. I was trying to create a custom register form - i.e: more fields other than just email - and here are the issues I've encoutered along the way:

1. I tried to create customized versions of functions defined in the Email module to render customized templates: **defaultEmailLoginHandler**, **defaultRegisterHandler**, **defaultForgotPasswordHandler**.

And it kept me wondering: why we can't simply provide a custom hamlet file and be done with it? Why do I have to create custom versions of those functions?

2. After the template part was done I moved to processing the forms, and here I hit the wall. I tried to create a custom version of the **registerHelper** function but, that is not a visible member of the Yesod.Auth.Email class
   so, creating a custom **registerHelper** won't work. Then I thought I could provide a custom route to process the form by rewriting **postRegisterR** and again I was out of luck.

Why those functions, particularly **registerHelper**, were not created as visible members of Yesod.Auth.Email?

3. My third attempt would be to "fork" the whole Email.hs module, but again I failed to meet some requirements to make this possible. In this case was the Yesod.PasswordStore that is not an exposed module, so I cannot import it into my custom Yesod.Auth.Email.

Why **Yesod.PasswordStore** was not exposed?

Given I don't want to go deeper into the rabbit hole and rewrite fork the PasswordStore, I just came to realize that it is not possible to have a custom registration form using Yesod.Auth.Email.

Am I missing something here or I got this right? Why Yesod.Auth.Email was built in that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly aware of the design decisions made by Michael Snoyman on this, but my reasoning was that "email" is the minimal information required to register an account. Once you have registered your email, a registration link email is sent to your account through which you can verify your account. It is on this password reset page, where I define all my custom fields along with setting new password. I define my own handler for setting new password. The code usually goes something like this:

```
  if (jpNewPassword profile == jpConfirmPassword profile)
    then do
      newPass <- liftIO $ saltPass (jpNewPassword profile)
      lift $
        runDB $
        do user <- getUser maid
           update maid [UserPassword =. (Just newPass)]
```

The above is a code from one of my personal projects.

> why we can't simply provide a custom hamlet file and be done with it?

Well you can still provide a custom hamlet file. This is how my `setPasswordHandler` is defined in the instance of `YesodAuthEmail`:

```
  setPasswordHandler _ =
    selectRep $
    do provideRep $ return $(shamletFile "./templates/password.shamlet")
```

> Why Yesod.PasswordStore was not exposed?

As explained above, you can still update the password without `Yesod.PasswordStore` being exposed. The [relevant functions](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-8.21/yesod-auth-1.4.17.2/Yesod-Auth-Email.html#v:saltPass) are in `Yesod.Auth.Email` module.

That being said, I can understand your concern. This is why I implemented JSON endpoints for all of the endpoints in `Yesod.Auth.Email` module so that validation and other stuffs can be easily done at client side itself. Those endpoints have been documented in the above linked Haddock page. But if you want to have custom fields in the registration page, I think it may involve some code change in `Yesod.Auth.Email` module. I would suggest you to open a issue in github (brownie points if you can also send a PR!) and give us the feedback there. We are very open to change!

Comment: about the hamlet template, what I meant is, why we couldn't have something like:
`
setPassWordLayout = "my-custom-template"
`

Regarding: "It is on this password reset page, where I define all my custom fields along with setting new password. I define my own handler for setting new password." so, your set password page (after registration) has extra fields? And so, you use a different route to process the form? given that **postPasswordR** cannot be rewritten in the instance of `YesodAuthEmail`

Comment: I want to understand those reasons before changing `Yesod.Auth.Email` and open a PR. Because if I'm taking this completely by the wrong side, then it is easier to change the way I'm approaching the problem than the other way around.

Comment: @ggarcia.jr Yes, my set password page has all the extra fields like first name, last name etc. And yes, I use a different route and set the password accordingly (along with updating new fields in the password page).

Comment: @Sibi, by "my own handler" do you mean creating a route separate from the subsite? If yes, what's the point of using the subsite then?